# Automatically generating field contents based on Year

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to create an automatically-generated field that follows this format:

TREQ-YY-NNNN

Where YY is the year submitted and NNNN is n<sup>th</sup> form submitted that year. For example:

TREQ-15-0001
TREQ-15-0002
TREQ-15-0003
TREQ-15-0004
TREQ-15-0005
TREQ-16-0001
TREQ-16-0002

I've been trying to use the Format property of an AutoNumber field but I get weird behavior when using the `TREQ-"yy"-"0000` mask. I end up getting values like TREQ-1899-01, TREQ-1900-02, TREQ-1900-03.

Is there a way for me to get the numbering format I am looking for, or something similar? I'm pretty new to Access and I'm still trying to learn proper syntax for the formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an AutoNumber field (which would not reset itself to `1` at the beginning of a new year) you could use a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) to automatically assign the key values to new records as they are inserted into the table. The macro would look something like this:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="no"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
  <DataMacro Event="BeforeChange">
    <Statements>
      <ConditionalBlock>
        <If>
          <Condition>[IsInsert]</Condition>
          <Statements>
            <Action Name="SetLocalVar">
              <Argument Name="Name">yy</Argument>
              <Argument Name="Value">Right(Year(Date()),2)</Argument>
            </Action>
            <Comment>Set default value in case no records found:</Comment>
            <Action Name="SetLocalVar">
              <Argument Name="Name">newSeq</Argument>
              <Argument Name="Value">1</Argument>
            </Action>
            <LookUpRecord>
              <Data Alias="z">
                <Query>
                  <References>
                    <Reference Source="tblTREQ" />
                  </References>
                  <Results>
                    <Property Source="tblTREQ" Name="KeyField" />
                  </Results>
                  <Ordering>
                    <Order Direction="Descending" Source="tblTREQ" Name="KeyField" />
                  </Ordering>
                </Query>
                <WhereCondition>[KeyField] Like &quot;TREQ-&quot; &amp; [yy] &amp; &quot;-*&quot;</WhereCondition>
              </Data>
              <Statements>
                <Action Name="SetLocalVar">
                  <Argument Name="Name">newSeq</Argument>
                  <Argument Name="Value">Val(Right([z].[KeyField],4))+1</Argument>
                </Action>
              </Statements>
            </LookUpRecord>
            <Action Name="SetField">
              <Argument Name="Field">KeyField</Argument>
              <Argument Name="Value">&quot;TREQ-&quot; &amp; [yy] &amp; &quot;-&quot; &amp; Right(&quot;0000&quot; &amp;
              [newSeq],4)</Argument>
            </Action>
          </Statements>
        </If>
      </ConditionalBlock>
    </Statements>
  </DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't get a chance to test this out until now but looks like this will work!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you shouldn't use an autonumber field for this - they are intended to have a unique number generated *by the system*, without user interference (just to make sure that each row has a unique ID to be referred to; it's like a predecessor of a GUID), and usually they aren't published. Typically, they would simply "number up" and have no concept to reset with the changing year. (which is why 1900 started at 2).

To generate your own (string!) keys, you need to write code that generates the key on post.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new `Text Box` in your form and in the `Control Source` field property in the `Data` tab, insert the following expression:

```
="TREQ-" & Right(Year([DateSubmitted]),2) & "-" & Format([ID],"0000")
```

where `[DateSubmitted]` is your date field and the `[ID]` is your autonumber field.

Or, you could create a local query like this:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.DateSubmitted, "TREQ-" & Right(Year([DateSubmitted]),2) & "-" & Format([ID],"0000") AS TreqNum
FROM Table1;
```

Hope this will help